# View of tab bar controller shifts downwards

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, sdk

I have a tab-bar controller app which has 19 views and therefore the "MORE" button needs to be pressed in order to switch to some of them.

The problem is that when I switch to a certain view which contains a Scroll View inside itself and which is positioned at index No 5 (therefore only selectable by clicking on the MORE button) when the view appears, it is shifted downwards by around 20 pixels I believe! The interesting thing is that if I edit the tab order and I move the view in question to position No 4 (therefore now selectable without clicking on the MORE button), then when the view appears it does not shift downwards anymore!

This downward shift does not occur to the other views which do NOT contain a Scroll View inside them. The Interface Building settings are identical across all views.

I've been trying to find a solution to this now for days and this is driving me absolutely insane! Is there anything else I should be doing?

Many many thaks!

[image]

Comment: Please post a screenshot.

Comment: well, you could show us some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! :-)

```
//***********************************************************************************
//There is a bug from Apple
//To avoid the view shifting down when changing the order of the tab views
//You must first create a new view and then assign the scroll view to this new view!
UIView *vi = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-10, -10, 1, 1)];
[vi setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self.view addSubview:vi];
//***********************************************************************************

//Now add the scroll view to the new view
[self.view addSubview:DesiredScrollerView];
```

[see here][1]